# Обратить последовательность массива без reverse в 30 символов

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, соревнование

Друзья, привет! Нужен коллективный разум.

Второй день бьюсь с задачей. Необходимо написать функцию reverse без использования Array.prototype.reverse() в 30 символов. Дошел до такого варианта, и похоже это мой предел в знаниях JS. (Такой вариант не подходит так как solution.length > 30)

```
let reverse=a=>[...a].map(a.pop,a)
```

Если кратко, [...a] - создает копию массива, мы проходимся по каждому элементу с помощью map и при помощи cb функции a.pop, с контекстом a, возвращаем обратную последовательность массива а.

Кто знает способ похитрей, поделитесь им, а лучше подскажите где копать.

Comment: а какие-то дополнительные особенности типа "нельзя переименовывать `reverse` до `r`" есть? xDD

Comment: т.к. никто не говорил, что переменная(функция) не может быть глобальной, то убираем `let ` и получаем 30 :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, действительно ... зачем хранить такую замечательную функцию не в глобальной област xDD

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо! Вот эту особенность не знал. Запомню. Спасибо, друг!

Answer (score 3):

Можно использовать **[sort](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)**. Суть в том, что функция сравнивает два значения за счет *compareFunction*, которую можно указать. И если в *compareFunction* возвращается 1, то элементы меняются местами. Вот отсюда можно и плясать. То есть в итоге не сравнивать элементы, а просто тупо всегда возвращать 1. Ну и так как нам не нужно сравнивать элементы, то и во входных данных их (аргументы) опускаем

```js
let reverse=a=>a.sort(a=>1); // 29
// let reverse=a=>a.sort(a=>1); // 28 - даже так работает

let myArray = [1, 5, 88, 3, 0, -666];
console.log(reverse(myArray));
```

Comment: implementation-defined получается же (где-то будет работать, где-то нет).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan речь идет о разных ЯП, разных входных данных или о чём?

Comment: Разных реализациях javascript. [If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the behaviour of sort is ***implementation-defined***.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11), там же, ниже, описано почему не consistent (не попадает под `a =CF a (reflexivity)`, т.к. для одинаковых значений возвращает не ноль).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan это же код-гольфный вопрос-ответ.И проверка по стандартам гольфа. Это явно не код, который должен применяться на боевых машинах. В итоге код, в общем случае, работает и решает поставленную задачу.